# loose index scan postgres subquery uses ungrouped column

Tags: postgresql

Following the link https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan I am trying to apply it to my case the following query:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
    SELECT MIN(test_table.entity_type) AS col FROM test_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT (SELECT MIN(col) FROM test_table WHERE col > t.col)
    FROM t WHERE t.col IS NOT NULL
    )
SELECT col FROM t WHERE col IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM test_table WHERE col IS NULL);
```

But I get the error:

> subquery uses ungrouped column "t.col" from outer query

Comment: Is there a column named "col" in test_table?  If so, aliasing `MIN(test_table.entity_type) AS col` is pretty darn confusing.  If not, then of course this isn't going to work, though the wording of the error message is not all that useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You must qualify all occurrences of `col` with the table name to avoid ambiguity.

So replace all occurrences of `col` with `t.col` or `test_table.col`.

Comment: what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: I have extended the answer.